# One run nested loop for every 1 run outer loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need looping outer 12 times and 1 looping inner for every outer loop

```
 for (let i = 0; i <= blocksForRow; i++) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    const block = document.createElement('div');
    block.classList.add('blocks__block')
    block.style.background = randomColors[random]
    fragmentForBlocks.appendChild(block)


    for (let x = 0; x <= blocksForColumn; x++) {
      const block = document.createElement('div');
      block.classList.add('blocks__block')
      block.style.background = 'red'
      fragmentForBlocks.appendChild(block)
    }
```

For example:

```
First iteration outer loop --> x iterations of inner loop
Second iteration outer loop --> x iterations of inner loop
```

etc.

But now my inner loop run all on first iteration outer loop.

Please help me how can I do this with for loops.

Comment: So if you have 12 "outer" loops, you want the "inner" loop to run 12 times per each "outer" loop??

Comment: Yeah, sorry for mistake, i want run x "inner" loops for every one "outer" loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can set a `var column = blocksForColumn` in the outer loop, like this:

```
 for (let i = 0; i <= blocksForRow; i++) {
    var column = blocksForColumn; // added
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    const block = document.createElement('div');
    block.classList.add('blocks__block')
    block.style.background = randomColors[random]
    fragmentForBlocks.appendChild(block)

    //changed blocksforColumn to column
    for (let x = 0; x <= column; x++) {
      const block = document.createElement('div');
      block.classList.add('blocks__block')
      block.style.background = 'red'
      fragmentForBlocks.appendChild(block)
    }
 }
```

Comment: But this doesn't change any behavior whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop is working correctly.
However, you just keep appendChild to `fragmentForBlocks` that's why every blocks will append itself only to the first row.

Maybe this solve your problem.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= blocksForRow; i++) {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  const row = document.createElement('div');     // create a row
  row.classList.add('blocks__block')
  row.style.background = randomColors[random]
  fragmentForBlocks.appendChild(row)            // append row to a thing.

  for (let x = 0; x <= blocksForColumn; x++) {
    const block = document.createElement('div');
    block.classList.add('blocks__block')
    block.style.background = 'red'
    row.appendChild(block);                      // append block to a row
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 0; i <= blocksForRow; i++) {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  const block = document.createElement('div');
  block.classList.add('blocks__block')
  block.style.background = randomColors[random]

  for (let x = 0; x <= blocksForColumn; x++) {
    const cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.classList.add('blocks__block')
    cell.style.background = 'red'
    block.appendChild(cell) // append the cell to the row
  }
  fragmentForBlocks.appendChild(block) // append the row
}
```

Try this. It should work for you. Here is what you are doing in the above code

- Creating a div and appending `x` cells to the div in the inner loop
- Creating a row and appending the inner loop `div`